# JS (Expected linebreaks to be 'LF' but found 'CRLF'.eslintlinebreak-style) issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code, frontend

I'm new in JS. I created table with checkbox row. Now I wanna test it. But I get error in my index.js file.

My code

```
import React from 'react';
import { Spin, Table } from 'antd';
import { useFetch } from 'innroad.common.ui';
import * as apiService from 'services/ApiService';

const AccountType = (onSelectingItems) => {
  const [data, isLoading] = useFetch(apiService.accountType);

  return (
    <Spin spinning={isLoading}>
      <Table
        key="id"
        bordered="true"
        rowKey="id"
        dataSource={data}
        rowSelection={{ onChange: onSelectingItems }}
        pagination={false}
      >
        <Table.Column title="Account Type" dataIndex="accountType" />
      </Table>

    </Spin>
  );
};

/* AccountType.propTypes = {
  selectionType: PropTypes.string,
  onSelectingLineItems: PropTypes.func,
}; */

AccountType.defaultProps = {
  selectionType: 'checkbox',
  onSelectingLineItems: () => { },
};

export default AccountType;
```

And one question more: should I use **AccountType.propTypes** - commented block? If yes, how I need change it? Because now I get error in this block - that I declare but didn't use.

Index.JS (Here is error)

```
export { default } from './AccountType';
```

**Expected linebreaks to be 'LF' but found 'CRLF'.eslintlinebreak-style after ";"**

Answer (score 10):

Click the LF / CLRF icon int he bottom right corner and change it to what you need.

[image: bottom right icon]

[image: select panel]

Alternatively you can change the rule in eslint

```
"linebreak-style": ["error", "windows"]
or
"linebreak-style": ["error", "unix"]
```

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/linebreak-style

You can also configure git to checkout with a choosen line ending style. This is often the cause of the reocurrence of the "problem".

For example

```sh
$ git config --global core.autocrlf true
# Configure Git to ensure line endings in files you checkout are correct for Windows.
# For compatibility, line endings are converted to Unix style when you commit files.
```

https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/using-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings

Answer (score 3):

In the bottom right corner you can change the line ending character:

[image]

Just change from CRLF to LF.

If you use Git, you can change this in automatic via configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Credits to one of my senior colleagues for this solution:

You can also add "`"linebreak-style": 0,`" to the `"rules"` section in package.json, which basically means to tell eslint to ignore the linebreak style (0 is for ignore).